# Emberjs. Helper not properly reading the parameter

Tags: ember.js

I am calling the helper like this:

metric.timestamp is well filled, I am logging it.

```
{{#each..
  ...
  {{#each.. itemController='..'}}
     ...
      {{#each metric in ... itemController='metric'}}
        {{log metric.timestamp}} //2014-09-16T14:35:02Z"
        {{#ifless12hours this date=metric.timestamp}}
```

Then, when I try to read it from the parameter, it is "". Can it be a problem of the
context?

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('ifless12hours', function(date,options) {

   Ember.Logger.log(date) // "" ??????

    var nowDate = new Date();
    var nowDateMil = nowDate.getTime();
    var dateAux = new Date(date);
    var dateMil = dateAux.getTime();

    if (Math.abs(dateMil-nowDateMil)<= 43200000){
      return options.fn(this);
    }
    else{
      return options.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: take away the `#` unless it is a block helper. i dont think you need to add `this`... (if it works for the log helper, it should work the same for your custom helper).. finally, parameters should be passed just as the bound property (`not date=`)... remember the {{log}} is an actual helper, so it should be a clue your custom helper should be called in a similar way.

Comment: If I delete # Error: each doesn't match ifless12hours {{ifless12hours}} ... {{else}} ... {{/if}}. how can I read the parameter in the helper then? (without date=)

Comment: well in that case, yes use the `#` i did not realize from your post that you are making and actual if style helper

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are passing `this` into your helper. But named options are not passed in as arguments. They will be passed in on the `options.hash`

If you create the helper like so:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('ifless12hours', function() {
  var options = [].slice.call(arguments, -1)[0];
  var context = (options.contexts && options.contexts[0]) || this;
  var date = options.hash.date;

  function dateCompare(date){
    var nowDate = new Date();
    var nowDateMil = nowDate.getTime();
    var dateAux = new Date(date);
    var dateMil = dateAux.getTime();
    return Math.abs(dateMil-nowDateMil)<= 43200000;
  }

  return Ember.Handlebars.bind.call(context, date, options, true, dateCompare);
});
```

You should be able to use it in your template like:

```
{{#ifless12hours date=metric.timestamp}}
  YUP
{{else}}
  NOPE
{{/ifless12hours}}
```

Working bin here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/siyuvi/2/edit

---

This helper is based off of the code found here: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/a-way-to-let-users-define-custom-made-bound-if-statements/2583/3

Comment: options.hash.date returns the string "metric.timestamp"

Comment: use `registerBoundHelper` instead

Comment: `registerBoundHelper` does not work with block helpers. I updated the answer to work as a bound block helper

Comment: you can also change the helper to work like `{{#ifless12hours date}}` instead of using `date=date` see http://emberjs.jsbin.com/siyuvi/3/edit for it working as a argument instead of a property